# VSTO Addin - Own button type like "ShapeWidth" and "ShapeHeight"

Tags: vsto, powerpoint, ribbon-control, ribbonx

I am currently working on an PowerPoint Addin and I am currently finishing the Ribbon. I'd like to create a control to change the size of objects that looks similar to the inbuild button "ShapeWidth" and "ShapeHeight":

[image]

However, I couldn't find the correct control type and hence I built the below by myself using an editbox and buttons. Although it's working I find the other style way cleaner but I haven't found the correct type.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Not all Ribbon X (Office Fluent UI) control types that Microsoft uses in its Office applications are made available to third-party developers. This, I'm afraid, falls into that category.

You should probably be able to get the image, at least, by specifying the `idMso` for the built-in control.